# REST Endpoints for Current User vs ID

Tags: rest, api, http, restful-architecture

As far as REST APIs go, which is the better structure to follow in general?

Assume `GET`/`PUT`/`POST`/`DELETE` for all resources.

1) Use currently signed in user for /users/**/* routes.

```
/users
/users/password
/users/email
/users/preferences
/users/documents
/documents/:id
```

2) Having absolute paths with IDs and using `/users/:id` for currently signed in user?

```
/users
/users/:id/password
/users/:id/email
/users/:id/preferences
/preferences/:id
```

Does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are fine. What's nice about creating unique endpoints for every user, is that one day you can allow user X to access information about user Y.

The pattern I followed in a recent API was to create a unique endpoint for every user, but 1 endpoint `/current-user` that redirects to the `/user/:some-id`.

A url might indicate an identity. It makes a lot of sense that other resources might refer to user as a 'creator' or 'modifier' of sommething, and in those places you might want to use a url (and not just a userId).

Answer (score 4):

If the resource you are referring can be multiple, you should go with

```
/resource/resource_id
```

In the above case, user can only be the current person, so using a pattern like `/users/user_id`, sounds odd. Because, you will have to handle different cases like What if a logged in **USER A** triggers an api call with a different user-id **USER B**??

You can have a namespace like `/profile` for managing the email, name, image etc. You don't have to make it as `/users/profile` as it is implicit that the data is going to be manipulated / accessed for the current logged in user.